# How to make .htaccess rules are not overwritten?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^product-([^/]+).html$ index.php?tid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^links-([^/]+).html$ index.php?page=links&lid=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+).html$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Problem:

If i put to home site directory file `test.html` it becomes invisible.

If i change my htaccess file rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^/]+).html$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^product-([^/]+).html$ index.php?tid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^links-([^/]+).html$ index.php?page=links&lid=$1 [L]
```

I have 404 error in url `/product-10.html` but `test.html` is available.

How to do so in both cases it worked (**test.html** must be available if exists and product-10.html must redirect to **index.php?tid=10**)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First ignore all real files and directories in a separate rule.

Use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^product-([^/]+)\.html$ index.php?tid=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^links-([^/]+)\.html$ index.php?page=links&lid=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.html$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Glad to know, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.